# Android Studio - error; package java.applet does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

import java.applet.Applet;

I used Android Studio 0.2.? sometime last year.  It worked fine.  Just updated to 0.5.7 incl. update SDK's, first time using it in months.  When I build a project it can't find any java imports.  "package java.applet does not exist" errors for every one.  And "cannot find symbol Applet".

Java installed @ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
JAVA_HOME & JDK_Home both set to the same
Project Structure has JDK set to the same

Tried installing Java 1.8u5 and change all the above with same results.

Edit: forgot to mention also uninstalled AS, deleted its folders and reinstalled 0.5.7.

I'm sure it's something simple, what am I missing?

Thansk,
Greg

Comment: applet? and android? why would you import applet in an android app?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? If you are making an applet in Android Studio, but not an Android app, have you tried compiling in another IDE, such as IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Thanks.  Your questions made me think enough to realize what I was doing.  I'm new to Android dev so was following a tutorial to get a feel.  I didn't realize the one I picked builds an app then ports it to Android.  The original question could probably be deleted.